# Do all skins come in all 5 conditions?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Do all skins available in game come in all 5 conditions?

For example, the Dual Beretta Demolitions has an awesome Orange color that reminds me of Time Crisis controllers, yet for what it's worth, the Steam Market doesn't have any that are Minimal Wear or Factory New.

I was under the assumption that skins came in all 5 conditions, Factory New, Minimal Wear, Field-Tested, Well-Worn, and Battle-Scarred.

Does this hold true for all other skins, or is this skin just a fluke?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Some skins dont have that 5 conditions. e.g.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't understand, what is this implying? This is from CSGOLounge, and merely shows the returns someone got.

Comment: @Slowpoke no, just searched in all. It contains all item types that the game has

Answer (score 5):

Not all skins come out in all five paint qualitys (conditions). A example is the Desert Eagle | Hypnotic or the MP9 | Hypnotic. Both are only avaible in Factory New or Minimal Wear.

The reason behind that is, that the skin would be look terrible if it is Well Worn.

If you create your own skin, you can configure, that the skin is only avaible in the qualitys you want.

The Dual Berettas | Demolition are **only available** with a wear level between 0.26 and 0.60 which is **Field-Tested**, **Well-Worn** and **Battle-Scarred**. You can look up these values on for example [CS:GO Stash](http://csgostash.com/).